# I don't understand why my css animation wont work

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I have an HTML page with a css animation i found on CodePen and I can't get it to work. It has sass in it and I know nothing about sass, do I have to convert the sass to regular css to any browser can read it? I need help. Thanks a hole lot!

The SCSS is : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nHkoi

Comment: SASS requires a pre-processor, you can't just copy SASS into a CSS sheet.  That said, just because the code is written in the SASS format doesn't necessarily mean it can't be done in regular old CSS.  It is possible you can just convert it to regular CSS first, but that depends on your animation.  I've not looked at the link you posted above, so I am NOT saying that it's possible with whatever you have above, but it might be.

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch That's exacly what I was looking for, got it to work! :D Thank you, I'd like to make that my choosen answer, I guess next time.

Answer (score 4):

SASS uses a lot of syntax that isn't compatible with CSS (nested classes, variables, etc.), so you'll either need to convert it to valid CSS by hand or run the file through the SASS command line tool. You can find the instructions here:

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the output in pure css

```
[1] http://sassmeister.com/gist/219a03d49f99bb906dd4
```

And here is a demonstration of the effect

```
[2] http://codepen.io/srekoble/pen/KzyqJ
```